# AS3 How to get width and height of external image

Tags: actionscript-3

I just try to load external image from HTML URL variable. 
Example : src="http://mysite.com/flash/load.swf?imageURL=http://mysite.com/img/image.jpg"

```
    var imageURL:String = this.loaderInfo.parameters.imageURL;
    var murl:URLRequest = new URLRequest(imageURL);
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(murl);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadProgress);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);


function loadProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
   var percentLoaded:Number = Math.round((event.bytesLoaded/event.bytesTotal) * 100);
   trace("Loading: "+percentLoaded+"%");
}

function loadComplete(event:Event):void
{
   trace("Complete");
   mc.addChild(loader);
}
```

And yes this is working.
But I want to know image width and height info.
For I try to do this for image info

```
    function loadComplete(event:Event):void
{
   trace("Complete");
  var bm:Bitmap = Bitmap(loader.content);
   var CXL = bm.width;
   var CYL = bm.height;
```

But it is not working.
Any advice please thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to extract the `content` or `bitmap` to get the width and height. Since Loader is a DisplayObject, it will have a width and height that is the same as the image loaded into it. So `loader.width` and `loader.height`.

Answer (score 1):

The event should have a target.content in it which is the bmp that was loaded, you should be able to get the widht/height from that.

```
function loadComplete(event:Event):void
{
   var bmp:Bitmap = event.target.content as Bitmap;
   trace("Complete width : "+ bmp.width);
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Is the width 0? or is the bmp object null?

Comment: it's break loading external image from HTML variable 
if I give inside AS3 direct image URL variable then it is work.